# whatsapp Chat-API fail [reason] => old_version

Tags: php, chat

Hello I am trying to get Whatsapp chat-api to work in php,
using the exampleRegister.php. I am trying to get the password from the server but it keeps giving me an error

```
=> fail [reason] => old_version ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a problem trying to request the code.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sendwhatsappmsg\Chat-API-master\Chat-API-master\src\Registration.php:316 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sendwhatsappmsg\Chat-API-master\Chat-API-master\examples\exampleRegister.php(41): Registration->codeRequest('sms') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sendwhatsappmsg\Chat-API-master\Chat-API-master\src\Registration.php on line 316
```

I already tried to update it with composer and download multi files from Github
all of them seem to give this error not sure what am doing wrong or maybe this api no longer works 
any help or tip will be welcome. 
If anyone know other Whatsapp api  or better way to send msg from localserver/php to Whatsapp users please share :)

Comment: Just alter at contants.php your version, but this api not work. When you fix this error, the next will be bad token. Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

For latest version you need to change in `composer.json` file like this

```
"require": {
    "whatsapp/chat-api": "dev-master"
}
```

After updating composer, you need to change the Constants like below

**Constants.php**

```
const WHATSAPP_VER = '2.18.8';
const WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT = 'WhatsApp/2.18.8 Android/4.3 Device/Xiaomi-HM_1SW';
```

**token.php**

```
$classesMd5 = 'CjxZj9h0ptjV2RRSfH9aYA==';
```

Hope this will fix both problems **(bad_token and old_version)**

Comment: Can you please explain how you obtained the token part? I really wish to know how to do this myself when whatsapp will update to a newer version (is this even a whatsapp thing)

Comment: I don't know exactly, but remembered only that I have done a lot of R&D on it then able to get this token. But I stop this because I am unable to send message, as you know this is not an official API.

Comment: Ye figured that out, couldn't send a message either because there was something wrong with the 'WHATSAPP_SERVER', the authentication server is something else than the sending 'WHATSAPP_SERVER', no clue how to solve this and don't want to xD I'm just going to use yowsup because that is still constantly updated ('https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup')

Comment: have you able to send message?

Comment: No not with chat-api, I havent tried the other one yet.

Comment: let me know if you succeeded

Answer (score 1):

Check the latest version of Whatsapp using google. eg:-2.17.286 (2017-08-08)
Then in the vendor/whatsapp/chat-api/src you'll find a file: Constants.php.
Update the following constants:

const WHATSAPP_VER = '**2.17.286**';
const WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT = 'WhatsApp/**2.17.286** Android/4.3 Device/Xiaomi-HM_1SW';

This solved my issue.

Comment: when you solve this, bad token error is received. :(

Answer (score -2):

U have to update var $classesMd5 in token.php.
Use this programm https://github.com/mgp25/classesMD5-64
(last toke is "5PhjPwAEWaaPFD4h3nM0hA==", also find here https://coderus.openrepos.net/whitesoft/whatsapp_scratch)

Also u have to update Constains.php , set

```
WHATSAPP_VER = '2.16.11'
WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT = 'WhatsApp/2.17.174 Android/4.4.4 Device/Samsung-Galaxy_S3
```

'